# Установить изображение как фон в QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qlabel

Проблема состоит в том, что если вносить путь к изображению явно - все работает. Но если вносить пусть через переменную - изображение не отображается.

```
    picute = r'pic\Drinks\Cola.jpg'     
    for_pic.setPixmap(QPixmap(picute))
```

> Это не работает

```
for_pic.setPixmap(QPixmap(r'pic\Drinks\Cola.jpg'))
```

> Это работает

Ошибка не в переменной.
 Пробовал и другие способы

```
for_pic.setStyleSheet('background-image:{0};'.format(r'pic\Drinks\Cola.jpg' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Справочник по таблицам стилей Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton


class WindowDemo(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self ):  
        super().__init__()

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setToolTip('Это текстовая метка')
        label1.setStyleSheet("QLabel{{border-image: url({});}}".format('./images/Ok.png'))
        label1.setFixedWidth(400)
        label1.setFixedHeight(400)

        btn1 = QPushButton(self )  
        btn1.setObjectName('btn1')
        btn1.setMaximumSize(48, 48)
        btn1.setMinimumSize(48, 48)
        style = '''
                    #btn1{
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        background-image: url('./images/add.png');
                        }
                    #btn1:Pressed{
                        background-image: url('./images/addhover.png');
                        }
                '''
        btn1.setStyleSheet(style)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label1)
        vbox.addStretch()
        vbox.addWidget(btn1)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("Установить изображение как фон в qLabel")

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    win = WindowDemo()  
    win.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Andreypavlenko что не так?